# Information on blocking it() calls in Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js, bdd

I am finding it inexplicably difficult to find information about if and why it() calls in Mocha are blocking. It appears that they are.

The following code, which works as intended, runs quite slowly because there are a large number of items to loop over, but more importantly the it() calls seems to block, such that one it() call will not start executing before the previous has finished.

```
var request = require('request');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var assert = require('assert');
var colors = require('colors');
var async = require('async');


describe('@Test_Enrichment*', function () {

    var config, constants, serverURL, serverPort;

    before(function () {
        config = require('univ-config')(this.test.parent.title, 'setup/testSetup');
        constants = config.get('sc_constants');
        serverURL = config.get('test_env').smartconnect_server_config.url;
        serverPort = config.get('test_env').smartconnect_server_config.port;
    });


   fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/test_data/enriched_payloads').filter(function (file) {

        return (path.extname(file) === '.json');

    }).map(function (file) {

        return __dirname + '/test_data/enriched_payloads/' + file;

   }).forEach(function (file) {

        it('[test] ' + path.basename(file), function (done) {   //this is the correct way to do it, but for every it() in the loop we have to wait for it complete before the next it is called
            var jsonDataForEnrichment = require(file);
            jsonDataForEnrichment.customer.accountnum = "8497404620452729";
            jsonDataForEnrichment.customer.data.accountnum = "8497404620452729";

            var options = {
                url: serverURL + ':' + serverPort + '/event',
                json: true,
                body: jsonDataForEnrichment,
                method: 'POST'
            };

            request(options, function (error, response, body) {
                if (error) {
                    done(error);
                }
                else {
                    assert(response.statusCode == 201, "Error: Response Code");
                    done();
                }
            });
        });

    });
});
```

----> is there a WAY to make it() asynchronous, so that that the it()'s can run in parallel?

more info: I opened an issue on Mocha's Github account here: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/1902#issuecomment-143071872

Comment: Interesting use of it(). however, would it not make more sense to put fs.readdirSync() inside your "test enriched payloads" test? Generally, the describe.it pattern should be plain and simple to read. Personally, I like to import a test helper to do the grunt work (e.g. blah.js, blah.spec.js + blah.test.js)

Comment: this use is documented on Mocha's website in the "dynamic" test section

Comment: you can see an issue opened on Github for Mocha here: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/1902#issuecomment-143071872